# Shell Script regex matches to array and process each array element

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, shell, centos

While I've handled this task in other languages easily, I'm at a loss for which commands to use when Shell Scripting (CentOS/BASH)

I have some regex that provides many matches in a file I've read to a variable, and would like to take the regex matches to an array to loop over and process each entry.

Regex I typically use https://regexr.com/ to form my capture groups, and throw that to JS/Python/Go to get an array and loop - but in Shell Scripting, not sure what I can use.

So far I've played with "sed" to find all matches and replace, but don't know if it's capable of returning an array to loop from matches.

Take regex, run on file, get array back. I would love some help with Shell Scripting for this task.

**EDIT**:
Based on comments, put this together (not working via shellcheck.net):

```
#!/bin/sh
examplefile="
asset('1a/1b/1c.ext')
asset('2a/2b/2c.ext')
asset('3a/3b/3c.ext')
"
examplearr=($(sed 'asset\((.*)\)' $examplefile))
for el in ${!examplearr[*]}
  do
    echo "${examplearr[$el]}"
  done
```

Comment: Your post is very vague but I can suggest `sed`, `awk` or `grep`. Do something like `array=($(sed 'regex' file))` and you will have an array.

Comment: That sounds pretty straightforward. Is there a Shell Script equivalent to https://jsfiddle.net/ ? I'd share code and write examples to post back here but for now I'll use sed as you noted and see what happens.

Comment: Yes there is. http://shellcheck.net.

Comment: Made a quick example but while on right track not sure where to go from there.

Comment: `examplearr=($(sed 'asset\((.*)\)' $examplefile))` will not work because `$examplefile` is not a file but a string. Change it to `examplearr=($(sed 'asset\((.*)\)' <<< $examplefile))`.

Comment: And you need a regex that will return the values you want. The current regex you have will not return what you thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

This works in bash on a mac:

```
#!/bin/sh
examplefile="
asset('1a/1b/1c.ext')
asset('2a/2b/2c.ext')
asset('3a/3b/3c.ext')
"
examplearr=(`echo "$examplefile" | sed -e '/.*/s/asset(\(.*\))/\1/'`)
for el in ${examplearr[*]}; do
  echo "$el"
done
```

output:

```
'1a/1b/1c.ext'
'2a/2b/2c.ext'
'3a/3b/3c.ext'
```

Note the wrapping of $examplefile in quotes, and the use of sed to replace the entire line with the match.  If there will be other content in the file, either on the same lines as the "asset" string or in other lines with no assets at all you can refine it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
examplefile="
fooasset('1a/1b/1c.ext')
asset('2a/2b/2c.ext')bar
foobar
fooasset('3a/3b/3c.ext')bar
"
examplearr=(`echo "$examplefile" | grep asset | sed -e '/.*/s/^.*asset(\(.*\)).*$/\1/'`)
for el in ${examplearr[*]}; do
  echo "$el"
done
```

and achieve the same result.

Comment: I've never used shellcheck.net, but changing to this: `examplearr=$(echo "$examplefile" | sed -e '/.*/s/asset(\(.*\))/\1/')` seems to satisfy it, and still works on mac.

Comment: The second example looks nearly perfect, but can't get it to work in shellcheck.net - have tried a few changes including:

examplearr=$(echo "$examplefile" | grep asset | sed -e '/.*/s/^.*asset(\(.*\)).*$/\1/')

Still no go.

Comment: Sorry, it appears "sh" on a Mac is (or at least acts as) an alias for bash, so while it works locally pure "sh" apparently has no concept of arrays.  When I checked it in on shellcheck.net maybe I had #!/bin/bash declared.. not sure.  I have access to pure sh on some work machines, may faff around some more.  Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. I'd do with GNU grep with perl-compatible regex (ah, delightful line noise):

```
mapfile -t examplearr < <(grep -oP '(?<=[(]).*?(?=[)])' <<<"$examplefile")
for i in "${!examplearr[@]}"; do printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${examplearr[i]}"; done
```

```
0   '1a/1b/1c.ext'
1   '2a/2b/2c.ext'
2   '3a/3b/3c.ext'
```

This uses the bash `mapfile` command to read lines from stdin and assign them to an array.

---

The bits you're missing from the sed command:

- $examplefile is text, not a filename, so you have to send to to sed's stdin
- sed's a funny little language with 1-character commands: you've given it the "a" command, which is inappropriate in this case.
- you only want to output the captured parts of the matches, not every line, so you need the `-n` option, and you need to print somewhere: the `p` flag in `s///p` means "print the [line] if a substitution was made".

```
sed -n 's/asset\(([^)]*)\)/\1/p' <<<"$examplefile"
# or
echo "$examplefile" | sed -n 's/asset\(([^)]*)\)/\1/p'
```

Note that this returns values like `('1a/1b/1c.ext')` -- with the parentheses. If you don't want them, add the `-r` or `-E` option to sed: among other things, that flips the meaning of `(` and `\(`